# Why was G'd "hiding" the good and evil knowledge from Adam and Eve?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, adam

My brother, an atheist, asked me that, but I did not know to answer him. If you stop and reflect, after eat the forbidden fruit, Adam and Eve knew a totally new world. They came out of a "dark cave" and were able to think for themselves.

Why is this so bad? Why Hashem, in his infinity goodness, would be hiding them the knowledge?

Comment: I'd be interested in any sources that explain that the "cave" they came out of was dark and the "world" was light, rather than the inverse.

Comment: For in much wisdom is much grief: and he that increases knowledge increases sorrow - Ecc.1:18

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Pedro! Thanks for sharing the question.

Comment: See Moreh Nevokhim (1:2).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would Adam and Chava have been permitted the tree of knowledge if they'd waited?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28182/would-adam-and-chava-have-been-permitted-the-tree-of-knowledge-if-theyd-waited)

Comment: The Rambam, in his guide to the perplexed says that before the sin there was no knowledge of good and evil, but rather of true and false. I've heard it explained that true and false is absolute, which good and evil is subjective (in the sense that what is good for one may be evil for another, and something may feel good but be bad for you).  You can see more here: http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp012.htm

Comment: http://www.chabaddayton.com/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/1101105/jewish/6-The-Naked-Truth.htm   and https://www.ou.org/torah/parsha/rabbi-sacks-on-parsha/the-art-of-listening/

Comment: I think the answer here would help answer this question as well http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28182/would-adam-and-chava-have-been-permitted-the-tree-of-knowledge-if-theyd-waited

Answer (score 2):

He did not "hide". As already pointed in comments, the "dark cave" is where they *entered*, not the previous state.

It is explained [perhaps Nefesh haHaim?...] that, before eating the fruit, they did *know* the good and evil, but it was like something 'outside'; and by eating, they 'mixed' the evil into themselves.

Before, there was also tenptation (for example, the Snake) but it was like the idea to put one's hand into fire: it is *possible*, but everybody knows that it is bad.      Now, we often do not know *what* is the evil -- it is **blended in ourselves**. And *this* is called **דעת** , to *mix* knowledge. But this is a *damage*.

[And, it is known (see in comments on the question) that, maybe the fruit would be permitted if they waited until Shabbos. So, it was just a matter of time.    Now consider that, you do not explain to your 4-years old son all the details on how to make a baby: he has time to learn, why disturbing him now... You nor "hide" him where to buy drugs or a gun... Just better to him not to know.]