# Is there still a prohibition on eating from the Eitz Hadaat (Tree of Knowledge)?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, gan-eden

Obviously this is a philosophical question, not a practical one, but I am curious to see if anyone has commented if whether the prohibition for eating from the Eitz Hadaat still stands today.

On the one hand, it would seem that the reason for not eating from the Tree is moot once the first transgression happened, but on the other hand, just because the reason no longer exists doesn't mean the issur goes away.

Comment: For those who think the Eitz haDaat was grapes or wheat or citrus or figs, then clearly the prohibition no longer applies.

Comment: @DoubleAA Was the Eitz HaDaas a species or a specific (Grape || Wheat || Citrus || Fig) tree?

Comment: I don't think the concept of a halachic *issur* applies to something that cannot possibly be done. The prohibition was specifically eating from that tree. I'm not following what @DoubleAA is hinting to, b/c there was never any prohibition even in Gan Eden to eat fruits from any other tree.

Comment: @danf I think he meant that it was the only one of that type. Therefore, since we eat that type now, the issue disappeared. I agree that it was a unique tree and all other trees even of that type were per

Comment: While hard to prove a negative, the words עץ הדעת do not appear in R. Perlow's edition to SHM of Rassag, or in Rambam's SHM, or in Ramban, Megillat Ester, Lev Sameah, and Marganita tava, to Rambam's SHM. Or in Yereim, Semag, Semak, Hinukh, Haredim, or Minhat Hinnukh. This would seem to indicate that it is not a mitsvah.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin לא שביק איתתא היתירא ואכיל איסורא

Comment: @mevaqesh it could be assur but not a mitzvah.

Comment: I have heard an opinion that the eitz hadaas is the SAME tree as the eitz  hachayim. This would seem to imply that after breaching the original command it's no longer assur, though would still be problematic...

Answer (score 1):

This is from logic only as I have not seen a discussion other than those who discuss what would have happened had Adam managed to refrain from eating the fruit. One could say that the fact that it is not mentioned again after the chait, implies that it was no longer relevant. Indeed, the only reason given for the expulsion and the guarding of the Garden is the *Aitz Hachaim*. Apparently, there was no problem if Adam would have eaten more or if he had refrained in the future from eating of the *Aitz Hadaat*.

Note that the mitzvos that apply to both Bnai Noach and Bnai Yisrael are only those that were repeated at Sinai. Those that were given before Har Sinai and not repeated were applied only to Bnai Yisrael. (Artscroll Sanhedrin 59a3). Aitz Hadaat was never mentioned and therefore would have been one of the 613 mitzos in the same way that *gid hanashe* is applied only to Bnai Yisrael (Art Scroll Sanhedrin 59a3 note 23). Since it is not considered one of the 613 mitzvos, then it could not have applied to the Bnai Noach before Sinai and therefore was never applied to Bnai Yisrael by not being repeated.

Sanhedrin 56b (ArtScroll 56b1 note 9) points out that Adam was previously allowed to eat all vegetation (and fruits in [Bereishis 1:29](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8165#v=29&showrashi=true)

> וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֱלֹהִ֗ים הִנֵּה֩ נָתַ֨תִּי לָכֶ֜ם אֶת־כָּל־עֵ֣שֶׂב |
>   זֹרֵ֣עַ זֶ֗רַע אֲשֶׁר֙ עַל־פְּנֵ֣י כָל־הָאָ֔רֶץ וְאֶת־כָּל־הָעֵ֛ץ
>   אֲשֶׁר־בּ֥וֹ פְרִי־עֵ֖ץ זֹרֵ֣עַ זָ֑רַע לָכֶ֥ם יִֽהְיֶ֖ה לְאָכְלָֽה:

Thus [Bereishis 2:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8166/jewish/Chapter-2.htm#v=16&showrashi=true)

> וַיְצַו֙ יְהֹוָ֣ה אֱלֹהִ֔ים עַל־הָֽאָדָ֖ם לֵאמֹ֑ר מִכֹּ֥ל עֵֽץ־הַגָּ֖ן
>   אָכֹ֥ל תֹּאכֵֽל:

appears to be redundant. Rav Yochanan learns that this teaches what we call the *Sheva Mitzvos Bnai Noach* and applies this to all future generations. The *Aitz Hadaat* is given explicitly in the next pasuk and is shown as not part of the previous pasuk, but a one time restriction for Adam alone.

Art Scroll 56b2 note 16 explains why *Eiver min hachai* is shown by the אָכֹ֥ל תֹּאכֵֽל of this pasuk. It appears to me to have been repeated because the permission to eat meat was granted and Hashem wanted to avoid a misunderstanding that perhaps *eiver min hachai* was now allowed as well.

Thus, *Aitz Hadaat* besides being impossible, and since Adam had already been made mortal for violating it, was not part of the general pasuk and therefore did not apply after the expulsion.

We can also say that only the *Aitz Hadaat* was forbidden and any other tree of that type would have been permitted. However, we do not know if this tree was unique in the garden or if there were any more of that type. We do not even know anything about it other than it was somewhere in the Garden. The Torah does not describe it or say anything about it other than

[Bereishis 2:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8166/jewish/Chapter-2.htm#showrashi=true&v=17)

> But of the Tree of Knowledge of good and evil you shall not eat of it,
>   for on the day that you eat thereof, you shall surely die."

Additionally, we see from [Would Adam and Chava have been permitted the tree of knowledge if they'd waited?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28182/would-adam-and-chava-have-been-permitted-the-tree-of-knowledge-if-theyd-waited) that there are those who explain that Adam would have been permitted to eat from the Aitz Hadaas after Shabbat. As a result, we see that from the very beginning, this command was a temporary command, designed to last only until Shabbat. Therefore, even as it is impossible after the expulsion, it no longer would have applied after Shabbat in any case. Indeed, it was a one time test that Adam could have passed or failed, similar to Akeidat Yitzchak which was a one time event that Avraham passed.

[The Tree of Knowledge](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2568/jewish/the-tree-of-knowledge.htm)

> Thus the Midrash tells us that if only Adam and Eve had waited until
>   the Sabbath, they would have been permitted to eat of the Trees of
>   Knowledge and Life, and the purpose of creation would have been
>   complete. This is an astounding concept: lf humans could follow G‑d's
>   commands on an external basis, for no apparent reason, they would
>   develop a special capacity that would enable them to fulfill their
>   potential for higher knowledge. That capacity was the ability to
>   achieve penimiut (inwardness). With this, all experience would be
>   integrated; without it, knowledge would remain external and
>   fragmentary. With it, they could indeed become like-G‑d. Without it,
>   they would remain knowledge-seeking humans.

[Bereishit 5775](http://www.aish.com/tp/ss/ssw/278945171.html)

> There is an idea that God wanted Adam to eat of the Tree of Knowledge
>   of Good and Evil, but only after first eating from the Tree of Life.
>   Adam needed to first internalize how to properly use knowledge before
>   eating of the fruit of that tree. He could have done so by not eating
>   the fruit of the Tree of Knowledge until God allowed it. Had Adam
>   eaten of the Tree of Life by obeying God, God would have allowed him
>   to eat from the Tree of Knowledge after the first Sabbath began.
>   Eating the fruit then would not have had negative consequences.

Comment: Mitzvos given to Bnei Noach not repeated at Har Sinai only apply to Jews (only example is Gid HaNasheh). See Sanhedrin 59. One of your main arguments is that only mitzvos given at Har Sinai apply to Jews - that’s just simply not true.

Comment: What is the difference between Gid HaNasheh and Eitz HaDaas? Both were given before Har Sinai and were not repeated at Har Sinai. Gid HaNasheh applies to Jews and only Jews, and you’re now saying that Eitz HaDaas, which should be no different, in fact applies to nobody? While I’m here, may I also note your paragraph about the Sheva Mitzvos - where do we see Noach being given mitzvos besides for Eiver Min HaChai and murder?

Comment: Except that’s not true - if Har Sinai means that the previous halachos are nullified, why can’t we eat Gid HaNasheh? (And you still haven’t proved that the Sheva Mitzvos were “reissued” to Noach. Only two are addressed in Bereishis 9.)

Comment: I should note that my comments regarding Gid HaNasheh only hold according to R’ Yehudah; according to the Rabbanan, the prohibition was stuck in at that point in the narrative retroactively. However, you still need to answer for R’ Yehudah.

Comment: No, *you* misunderstand. Sanhedrin 59a explicitly refers to Gid HaNasheh as being taught to Bnei Noach and not repeated at Sinai.

Comment: OOPs now I see it. Of course gid hanashe never applied to bnai noach in general only to the sons of Yaakov (though they were Noachides at the time). I would have learned that as the reason. However, I will have to redo my post to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The prohibition is not in effect.

The Gemara in Sanhedrin 56a-60a lists several prohibitions incumbent on Bnei Noach; a fuller treatment of this is discussed in a related answer of mine [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77476/). The important thing to note is that the prohibition of eating the Eitz HaDaas is not on this list.

From the fact that it’s not applied to non-Jews, we can deduce that the original prohibition did not hold; therefore, it would have to be retaught at Sinai to apply to Jews. Since it wasn’t, we can conclude that it doesn’t apply to Jews, either.