# Adam and Chava's lack of repentance

Tags: parashat-bereishit, repentance-teshuvah, adam, gan-eden

I searched but did not find this exact question. Were Adam and Chava's expulsion also in part due to their lack of repentance or was it specifically because of their disobedience?

Comment: Are those the only 2 choices? Gen 3:22 indicates that it is a natural consequence (that man's new nature makes him unsuitable for the garden) and a preventative (so that man doesn't eat of the tree of life).

Comment: Who says that they did not repent?

Comment: this requires a source that it is not because of repentance, that's a tall order

Comment: @sabbahillel. They did not acknowledge the sin, offer any explanation or apologize. They each blamed the other. Where is record of t'shuvah on their part?

Comment: @Ephraim there is a Medrash that they wanted to repent but did not know it was possible or how to do it. When Kayin got the sign and tried to repent, Adam learned about repentance. There are commentators that connect this to the delay until Shes was born

Comment: @sabbahillel Thank you for the response. If we take the Midrash into consideration, could we conclude they were expelled for their disobedience only?

Comment: I would conclude that the necessity of the expulsion was because the change in the nature of the world made it impossible for them to live within the miraculous conditions of Gan Eiden. Remember that creation was still *going on* as it was not yet complete. Had they waited until Motazaei Shabbos when they would have been allowed to eat of both trees, things would have been different. However, that is a major discussion and not a subject for a quick comment. (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28182/would-adam-and-chava-have-been-permitted-the-tree-of-knowledge-if-theyd-waited)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the Ohr HaChaim Hakodosh seems to suggest that towards the end of his Perush of [Ch. 3 Verse 22](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01424_part_1.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2).

In short: *Because of his unwillingness to acknowledge his sin he had to be expelled so that he wouldn't eat from the Tree of Life.*

> ולפי דרך זה נשכיל מאמר אחד תמוה (ב''ר פכ''א) וזה לשונם ועתה פן ישלח ידו אמר ר' אבא בר כהנא מלמד **שפתח לו הקב''ה פתח של תשובה** דכתיב ועתה אין ועתה אלא תשובה שנאמר (דברים י) ועתה ישראל מה וגו', והוא אמר פן אין פן אלא לאו, אמר הקב''ה ישלח ידו ואכל ואם אכל וחי לעולם עכ''ל. דבריהם ז''ל תמוהים ביותר איך יוצדק לומר ה' לאדם שיחזור בתשובה וימרוד מרד גדול כזה לומר לא. עוד למה לא חש ה' שיאכל אלא כשאמר לא. והיה נראה לומר **כי אם היה עושה תשובה** לא היה ה' מקפיד על חיותו לעולם וזה אינו כי כבר נתחייב מיתה ביום אוכלו מעץ הדעת: ‏
>
> ולפי דרכנו יבואו על נכון דברי רבותינו ז''ל כי ה' רצה להודיע להאדם כי חטא באכילתו ובאמצעות הכרתו כן הוא מעצמו יבדל מלאכול מעץ החיים כמו שכתבנו למעלה כי הוא זה תיקונו, ולזה **אמר לו שיעשה תשובה ומשמעות תשובה יגיד כי פשע, והאדם השיב לאו פירוש כי לא חטא שיצטרך לשוב, וטוען טענה הנשמעת כי לא ידע בה ואינו אלא שוגג ואינו צריך לעשות תשובה, וכיון שטען כן אמר ה' מעתה ישלח ידו ואכל שאין לו מונע כפי סברתו, לזה שלחו ה'** כי משפטו נחתם למות על אכילתו מטעם שכתבנו. ואחר כך שב ונכנס במי גיחון ק''ל שנה לכפרת עון:‏